# Edited /fstab, ruined everything, need help

Tags: boot, mount

I run Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox from a Windows 7 OS, I ran into some problems this morning, started troubleshooting which lead to me editing my fstab file, I think I deleted out an essential UUID.

I'm currently getting this screen: http://prntscr.com/9nm4u2 followed by this if I try and ignore: http://prntscr.com/9nm6fo

Please can someone offer advice as to how to get back onto Ubuntu, I just want to backup my files and reinstall.

I really know nothing about this low-level stuff, GRUB, kernel etc child friendly instructions would be really appreciated. I'm pretty certain I've not posted the information I need to in order for you to help me, I'll post whatever necessary.

Thanks

Comment: Press `M` (for manual recovery) and post the output from `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9nmqo9

There was a line below "# swap was on", I'm annoyed I didn't mute rather than delete.

Comment: Also post the output of `sudo blkid`

Comment: sudo blkid: http://prntscr.com/9nrvwz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Enter recovery mode and type:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
2. Now type:

   ```
   nano /etc/fstab
   ```
3. This should open a command line text editor. From there, change this line:

   ```
   UUID=9afb49b5-0651-4775-8a47-6f4bb3d0f682 ext4 errors=remout-ro 0 1
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   UUID=9afb49b5-0651-4775-8a47-6f4bb3d0f682 / ext4 errors=remout-ro 0 1
   ```
4. Below `# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation`, add this line:

   ```
   UUID=586732aa-c190-466b-9b50-51ca650e7010 none swap sw 0 0
   ```
5. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save changes, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the editor.
6. Type either `poweroff` or `reboot`.

Comment: When I try and edit this I get an error reading: Error writing /etc/fstab: Read-only file system

Comment: @EatsIndigo: I've updated my answer to solve the "read-only filesystem" problem and to enable your swap

Answer (score 0):

The thing that jumps out at me is that your fstab entry is missing the mount point.  There should be a "/" after the UUID.

`UUID=[whatever] / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1`

`UUID=[swapUUID] none swap sw`

Comment: Details posted above for sudo blkid and, outcome when trying to edit forward slash into fstab. - thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to include the line for the swap.  If you edit your fstab to include these two lines and reboot I think you will be OK.  I'm not familiar with recovery mode but in normal ops you have to edit this file as root by using the `sudo` command.

Comment: Thanks, my fstab is a "read only file system" which is preventing me from editing, will I be able to chmod that?

Comment: Not sure about recovery mode.. possible answer here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/cannot-edit-fstab-in-recovery-mode-filesystem-is-read-only-540195/

Comment: Best answer looks like Run system in single user(recovery) mode.
You need to re-mount filesystem with write-read access.

# mount -o remount,rw / - should do

Change fstab.
Re-mount filesystem with read-only
Reboot

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I'm back in. 

Your linuxquestions link pointed me to the answer

Comment: You're welcome.  If it helped you, please upvote and /or accept my answer by clicking on the gray checkmark to the left.